# Replacing the speaker on iPad 3 - What adhesives I need and where I buy them?

Tags: ipad

I am about to replace the speaker on an old iPad 3 I have.

I know that the iPad is glued in a lot of places and that these apple devices use adhesives in form of double sided tapes that are cut in precise forms.

Before I replace the speaker, I need to have to purchase these adhesives.

I found the speaker at [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Loud-Speaker-Ringtone-Ringer-Internal-Sound-Buzzer-For-iPad-3-3rd-iPad-4-4th/221937477649?_trkparms=aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20200520130048%26meid%3Dd495d82098e949b38110981ee186aaa7%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D12%26mehot%3Dco%26sd%3D192690769552%26itm%3D221937477649%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DSimplAMLv5PairwiseWebWithDarwoV3BBEV2b%26brand%3DUnbranded&_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851)

But what adhesives do I need and where to purchase them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iFixit sells [adhesive strips](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPad/iPad-3-4-Adhesive-Strips/IF116-016?o=1) for that model.

Comment: ok. But as far as I saw on a video, even the battery and other parts are glued and these you show appear to be just the main adhesives...